# Bot not sending any message

Tags: telegram-bot, esp32, arduino-ide

I'm currently working on programming an ESP32 to control a Telegram bot. The goal is to have the bot send a message once the connection to Telegram is successfully established.

I have successfully set up the ESP32 to connect to the Telegram API using the UniversalTelegramBot library. However, I'm encountering an issue where the bot does not send any messages.

I have verified that the ESP32 is connected to the Telegram API by checking the connection status. It shows as connected, but the messages are not being sent. I have also double-checked the bot token and the chat ID, and they are correct.

Here is  my code:

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include "UniversalTelegramBot.h"
#include "EEPROM.h"

#define LENGTH(x) (strlen(x) + 1)
#define EEPROM_SIZE 200
#define WIFI_RESET 0
String ssid;
String password;
unsigned long millis_RESET;

#define BOT_TOKEN "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN"  // Reemplaza con el token de tu bot
WiFiClient client;
UniversalTelegramBot bot(BOT_TOKEN, client);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(WIFI_RESET, INPUT);
    if (!EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE)) {
        Serial.println("Failed to init EEPROM");
        delay(1000);
    } else {
        ssid = read_flash(0);
        Serial.print("SSID = ");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        password = read_flash(40);
        Serial.print("Password = ");
        Serial.println(password);
    }

    WiFi.begin(ssid.c_str(), password.c_str());

    delay(3500);

    if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
        WiFi.beginSmartConfig();

        Serial.println("Waiting for SmartConfig.");
        while (!WiFi.smartConfigDone()) {
            delay(500);
            Serial.print(".");
        }

        Serial.println("");
        Serial.println("SmartConfig received.");

        Serial.println("Waiting for WiFi");
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
            delay(500);
            Serial.print(".");
        }

        Serial.println("WiFi Connected.");

        Serial.print("IP Address: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

        ssid = WiFi.SSID();
        password = WiFi.psk();
        Serial.print("SSID:");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        Serial.print("password:");
        Serial.println(password);
        Serial.println("Store SSID & password in Flash");
        write_flash(ssid.c_str(), 0);
        write_flash(password.c_str(), 40);
    } else {
        Serial.println("WiFi Connected");
    }

    // Intentar establecer conexión con el bot de Telegram

    if (client.connect("api.telegram.org", 443)) {
        Serial.println("Bot Connected");
        // Envía un mensaje de conexión exitosa al bot de Telegram
        String message = "Conexión exitosa. El dispositivo se ha conectado a Wi-Fi.";
        bot.sendMessage("YOUR_CHAT_ID", message);
        Serial.println("Prueba");
    } else {
        Serial.println("Failed to connect to Bot");
    }
}

void loop() {
    millis_RESET = millis();
    while (digitalRead(WIFI_RESET) == LOW) {
    }

    if (millis() - millis_RESET >= 5000) {
        Serial.println("Reseting the WiFi credentials");
        write_flash("", 0);
        write_flash("", 40);
        Serial.println("Wifi credentials erased");
        Serial.println("Restarting the ESP");
        delay(500);
        ESP.restart();
    }

    // Resto del código
}

void write_flash(const char* toStore, int startAddr) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < LENGTH(toStore); i++) {
        EEPROM.write(startAddr + i, toStore[i]);
    }
    EEPROM.write(startAddr + i, '\0');
    EEPROM.commit();
}

String read_flash(int startAddr) {
    char in[128];
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 128; i++) {
        in[i] = EEPROM.read(startAddr + i);
    }
    return String(in);
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully send messages from the ESP32-controlled Telegram bot.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If you are trying to connect to port 443 (secure connection), then you need to use `WiFiClientSecure secured_client;` instead of `WiFiClient`, in fact if you read (or try) the examples that come with the library, you should noticed that.

Comment: I changed the port to port 80 but the bot is still not sending any message.

Comment: As I said, what you need to change is using the secure client, not change it to the non-secure port 80, no public-facing website or api nowadays accept port 80, even you sent to port 80, it will be redirect to 443. Read the API documentation about the telegram bot and try the examples that come with the library!

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```cpp
WiFiClientSecure client;
client.setInsecure();
UniversalTelegramBot bot(BOT_TOKEN, client);
```

Instead of:

```cpp
WiFiClient client;
UniversalTelegramBot bot(BOT_TOKEN, client);
```